# expressing return semantics in interface definition

Tags: c#

I have an interface

```
interface IFooWidget
{
     IWidget Get(string widgetName);
}
```

My question is - how do I tell implementers the return semantics for the error case?  I mean if they cant find the requested widget should they throw or return a null value. This seems a vital part of the interface definition but I cannot express it.

Seems like documenting it is the only way - it would be much nicer if I could somehow put it in compiler-speak rather than human-speak.

Just wondering if anybody has any solutions or thoughts...

Consensus Answer:

Interface define syntax not semantics. I was allowing myself to be seduced by the englishness of my method definition. Imagine if it was instead

```
IWidget Fnargle(string wobbler);
```

Which is of course how it looks to the compiler. The call semantics were hinted at in the original question because I chose a method name and params that were supposedly helpful. But really I need to document all aspects of the semantics of the method - not avoidable

Comment: seems like an opportunity to take a jab at C# for not implementing `throws` like Java...

Comment: actually 'throws' doesnt help. I want to know if the Get method will throw or return null if it cant find the widget. 'throws' just says - this method can throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to formally document or enforce this in C#.

Actually, interfaces do not express a lot of stuff. They do not express pre- and post-conditions on the data passed in or out. They *do* express the data format (type and number of arguments) but that is a small part of the contract of any given method.

There are some tools trying to help here. Code contracts comes to mind. They only create a different way to express these conditions. They do not statically enforce them.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to specify which exceptions might be thrown from a method - C# does not have checked exceptions similar to Javas. You could add a parameter for an exception handler if you want to ensure the caller will handle any error:

```
interface IFooWidget
{
     IWidget Get(string widgetName, Action<ExceptionType> handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that you can express this in C# (as in most other modern languages).

IMHO I think an interface is precisely for not expressing any implementation details; if you want your method (the one specified by the interface) to return something only if a particular condition is true I would tend to say that this is rather an implementation detail.

Methods defined in interfaces are the least common part of all possible implementations i.e. the methods signature not any statement on how the method should be (or must) implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is an option to specify this in the interface.  One option is to add comments like you suggested.  A comment like the one below will show up in IntelliSense for the implementer.

```
/// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
```

If you are using .Net 4.5, you can use the System.Diagnostics.Contracts Namespace to specify a post condition to ensure that the result is not null using [Contract.Ensures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412871.aspx).  Unfortunately adding a contract to an interface is a bit of a pain.  The Microsoft docs on [ContractClassAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contractclassattribute.aspx) gives the details on how to do this.